# combine 2 strings in one with some elements

Tags: php, mysql

The code looks like this:

```
$link .= '/'. . 'elevi' . .'/'. $clasa . '/' . $litera . '/' .  $nume .'-'. $prenume;
```

But the error apear :

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '.' in ...

But if the code looks like this :

```
$link .= $clasa . '/' . $litera . '/' .  $nume .'-'. $prenume;
```

Works like this :

```
11/c/bobo-alex
```

and i want it to looks like this

```
./elevi/11/c/bobo-alex
```

with [dot] and slash first

Comment: This one: `$link .= './'. $clasa . '/' . $litera . '/' .  $nume .'-'. $prenume;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to many string combining dots in your first segment.

You can also use "" instead of '' for PHP to auto-echo variable contents to the string.

```
$link .= "./elevi/$clasa/$litera/$nume-$prenume";
```

Answer (score 0):

The dots are used to concatenate two strings, so you can't put two dots consecutive, it will rise a syntax error, so you can do it in two ways:

```
$mystring = './' . $var1 . '/' . $var2 . '/' . $var3 . '-' . $var4;
```

or:

```
$mystring = "./$var1/$var2/$var3-$var4";
```